# ImportError: No module named rest_framework_mongoengine

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

I have installed both DjangoRest framework and Mongo Engine using pip, included `rest_framework_mongoengine` in `INSTALLED_APPS` list. Still exception is being thrown when I run server.

> File "/Users/anum/Desktop/Python/ConnectBox/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
>   fn(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/anum/Desktop/Python/ConnectBox/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
>   autoreload.raise_last_exception()
>
> File "/Users/anum/Desktop/Python/ConnectBox/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 250, in raise_last_exception
>   six.reraise(*_exception)
>
> File "/Users/anum/Desktop/Python/ConnectBox/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
>   fn(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/anum/Desktop/Python/ConnectBox/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 27, in setup
>   apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>
> File "/Users/anum/Desktop/Python/ConnectBox/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
>   app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
>
> File "/Users/anum/Desktop/Python/ConnectBox/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
>   module = import_module(entry)
>
> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
>   **import**(name)
>
> ImportError: No module named rest_framework_mongoengine

Here is my [Settings.py](https://ghostbin.com/paste/zj29o).

Using **pip list** command, following packages were listed down:

```
Django (1.11.2)
djangorestframework (3.6.3)
mongoadmin (0.2)
mongodbforms (0.3)
mongoengine (0.13.0)
pip (9.0.1)
PyJWT (1.5.2)
pymongo (3.4.0)
pytz (2017.2)
setuptools (36.0.1)
six (1.10.0)
wheel (0.29.0)
```

Please help me to get in right direction.. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to install:

**pip install django-rest-framework-mongoengine**

Answer (score 2):

You need to install rest_framework_mongoengine; it is a separate package.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mongo engine package
 
**from pypi**
pip install django-rest-framework-mongoengine

**from github**

- download some release from github, unpack somewhere.
- copy subdir unpacked_path/rest_framework_mongoengine into your django project or inside python path
- or, install using pip unpacked_path

**Include the packages in Django settings.**

INSTALLED_APPS = (

```
...
'rest_framework'
'rest_framework_mongoengine',
...
```

)

For More Ref: https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine

Answer (score 0):

add these in settings.py file

INSTALLED_APPS = (

...
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework_mongoengine',
...
)

If you are working in virtualenv ,then install this module in python directory path

C:\Python34\Scripts> pip install django-rest-framework-mongoengine

instead of env path
C:\Python34\Scripts\env\Scripts> pip install django-rest-framework-mongoengine